# Set ImageURL without knowing the file extension c#

Tags: c#, image

I have a folder where images are uploaded and named 'Photo1', 'Photo2', etc depending on how many photos are uploaded. In another panel on the same aspx page I want to display the uploaded photos. I will know the filenames but the extension could be .png, .jpg, or .jpeg.

How can I set the ImageUrl path when I know only the filename and not the extension?

Here is an example of how I've attempted it so far--

ASPX Page Code:

> `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />`

Code Behind:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/RepairPhotos/" + order_id + "." + unit_id + ".RepairPhoto1.*");
```

This method says I've used an invalid character. Although, I've tested it by going into the folder and finding the extension then entering the line as:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/RepairPhotos/" + order_id + "." + unit_id + ".RepairPhoto1.jpg");
```

and that didn't work either, so there may be more wrong here than just the unknown character in the extensions place.

Answer (score 1):

```js
string jpg = "~/RepairPhotos/" + order_id + "." + unit_id + ".RepairPhoto1.jpg"
string png = "~/RepairPhotos/" + order_id + "." + unit_id + ".RepairPhoto1.png"
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(jpg)))
{

}
else if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(png)))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the file's extension, you may need to read the first few bytes of that file to determine if an image is in what format.

This snippet may help: https://gist.github.com/ChuckSavage/dc079e21563ba1402cf6c907d81ac1ca